# If you have two class CSS selectors, do they have a decendent relationship and does this hierarchical relationship need to be mirrored in the HTML?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

In my CSS, I'm using 2 class selectors (Twitter bootstrap w/ 30 columns):

```
.row-fluid .span9 {
width: 29.5597485%;
*width: 29.50766516666667%;
}
```

How do I ensure that this rule is being applied?  Neither of my attempted HTML set-ups seems to work.  Is one of these proper syntax, or is there another way to ensure the CSS rule above is being applied to the HTML?

HTML Idea 1:

```
<div class="row-fluid span9">
```

HTML Idea 2:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span9">
```

Comment: Debug using tools like firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first markup will not apply based on your CSS.

`.row-fluid .span9` means an element with class `.span9` as a descendant of `.row-fluid` so it won't match HTML 1. It would match HTML 2.

- First HTML example is matched by `.row-fluid.span9`.
- Second HTML example is match by `.row-fluid .span9`, or `'.row-fluid > .span9` if you want to ensure only direct children of `.row-fluid`.

It's also possible you are correctly matching the CSS selectors, but your styles are being overruled by higher specificity of the bootstrap default styles. In this case throw a `!important` at the end of you styles to test. It will overrule.

I'd recommend using FireBug, or another HTML inspector which will help you debug CSS issues in a much faster way than trial and error.

Comment: `.row-fluid > .span9` isn't any more specific (in terms of CSS) than either `.row-fluid .span9` or `.row-fluid.span9`.

Comment: @BoltClock terminology may have been off, but `.row-fluid > .span9` ensures direct child relationship, vs. `.row-fluid .span9` which selects ANY `.span9` as a child, grandchild, etc. of `.row-fluid`. That was my point.

Answer (score 1):

The rule you mention will only apply to idea #2 (idea #1 would need `.row-fluid.span9` -- without a space between the classes).

Regarding debugging: here's a screenshot that shows how easy it is to see exactly what CSS rules apply (and also what rules apply but are overridden by others) to each element. The siderbar at the far right not only displays this information, but it also allows you to disable/enable individual rules. The CSS file/line numbers are also clickable.

Did I mention that when it comes to development Chrome blows everything else out of the water? :)

[image: Chrome developer tools example]

[Link to full-size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGRlQ.png).

Answer (score 0):

If your rule is in a CSS file or `<style>` tag that appears in your document **before** bootstrap.css is loaded, then your rule will be overridden by bootstrap.

You can do two things to make your rule take precedence. You can give it a higher 'value' by expanding the rule itself:

```
div.row-fluid div.span9 {
  width: 29.5597485%;
  *width: 29.50766516666667%;
}
```

Or, you can use the `!important` modifier:

```
.row-fluid .span9 {
  width: 29.5597485% !important;
  *width: 29.50766516666667% !important;
}
```

Finally, these rules will only apply to your second HTML snippet. To apply a rule to a single element with two classes, you would need to do:

```
.row-fluid.span9 {  // notice the lack of spaces
  ....
}
```

Although, not sure why you're overriding bootstrap's width settings anyway.